# Dwell clicking software that supports right-dragging and allows to define shortcuts for Kubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, kubuntu, mouse, accessibility

Is there any dwell clicking software for Kubuntu 14.04 LTS x64 or Kubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 that supports the following features:

- left and right-dragging
- double/triple click
- a shortcut can be defined to change the mouse mode
- the mouse mode window is always on Top

?

---

A few definitions:

- Right-dragging = you click the right mouse button while pointing at something, hold down the right mouse button and drag the object somewhere
- [Dwell clicking](http://www.bltt.org/quicktips/mouse_dwell.htm) = Instead of having to press a mouse button or a switch the user needs to simply hold the mouse steady in an area for a predefined amount of time. This action issues the computer with a 'virtual' click and provides the same function as if someone had pressed the mouse button.

---

On Windows I use [Point-N-Click](http://www.polital.com/pnc/) dwell clicking software: it has all the above-mentioned features (and is free).

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: how about using wine or other similar programs to run the program in Ubuntu?

Comment: @Woeitg: Thanks for the suggestion, that's indeed a possibility. Ideally I would prefer a native solution though.